# How to find specific IP address within LAN?

Tags: network, wifi

With the setup I used to have I was able to control the home-domotica system via the wireless network of the time-capsule (app iPhone).

10.0.1.152

However today I had to move the time-capsule to it's permanent place.
This meant a change in the setup.

Where it used to be that the time-capsule and the domotica system were plugged-in in the same switch there is now a second switch involved.

Internet

|

Router

|

Switch - Domotica system

|

Switch - time-capsule

Now this has of course an influence on all. Yet I cannot find out the IP address the app should contact.

arp -a Gave me a list. Initially I got 9 hits. But none of them work.

A nasty side-effect is that I cannot access some of the lights anymore....
Need to find a way to access the correct address through 2 switches...

Comment: There is an app "Bonjour Browser" which scans the local network for available services.  You can download it from http://www.tildesoft.com/

Answer (score 1):

So the router is the only DHCP server, right? It is the only device giving out IP addresses, and the switches (including the time-capsule) just redirect the traffic (i.e. bridge mode), right?

If I am not mistaking, the client list in your router should provide you with the list of all connected devices with mac-addresses and ip-addresses (and sometimes device names). Try and see if the mac address of your device is in there.

Comment: Would indeed be a great way. Unfortunately the only way to find out the MAC address of the device is via utp and it does not find it...
At least according to it's very basic software.
It could be an option to check the list gotten via [ arp -a ] and check all other devices and the last one would be the correct one. However it doesn't matter which address 10.0.1.1 - 10.0.1.255 I use I do not find the device anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this will teach me not to fiddle around at 2:00 am with a sleepy head.
It turned out I had the device plugged-in on the time-capsule (explaining the 10.0.1.152 address) 
With me changing the whole setup as it needs to be.... (sort of) I forgot the fact that the domotica system was plugged-in on the time-capsule and just used a switch. Of course giving a problem.

I would have to place a different router between the internet modem and switch...
Which is a shame as the internet modem of the internet provider has it all onboard. Yet I had to switch it off so I could keep using the time-capsule as the wifi manager...

I have to rethink the setup...